# Example of ideal intersect subring that is non-ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with identity. If subrings are assumed to contain identity, does there exist an ideal $I$ and a subring $S$ of $R$, where $I\cap S$ is not an ideal of $R$?

Comment: This question strikes me as bizarre, because for tons of, if not for most, familiar rings, proper subrings of $R$ don't contain ideals of $R$ at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $R=\Bbb Z[x]$, $S=\Bbb Z[x^2]$ and $I=(2)$. Multiplying by $x$ takes you out of $I\cap S$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that if $R = \mathbb F_p$ then $R$ does not contain proper subrings with unity.

So let's assume that $S \subsetneq R$ is given. Then $I = R$ is an ideal and $I \cap S = S$. But because $S$ contains $1$ and is a proper subset of $R$, it cannot be an ideal.